# Regex to allow decimal number not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regex to allow decimal numbers but it not accepting the decimal numbers.can anyone tell me what is wrong in my regex code.

```
export const ddd = (value) => value.replace(/[^\d]+(\.\d{1,2})?$/, '').slice(0,7);
```

Expected Output is: 
 55.69

But the actual output i am receiving is 
  5569

Comment: It may be a broader problem, it would be better if you showed the whole relevant code.

Comment: You probably meant `^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$`

Comment: So, a decimal number should start with any amount of non-digits?

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar indeed, even if it was a typo and OP meant to put `^` outside the braces, then it's still a bit strange what the intended output is. If the *entire* value is a decimal number, it'd be removed and you'd still try to take the first 8 characters from the resulting (empty) string.

Comment: `[^\d]+`  is one or more nondigits. `^\d+` is starting with one or more digits

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear what you're asking, but this may be of help.

```
[^\d]+     Match one or more NON-digit
(          Start capture group
  \.       Literal .
  \d{1,2}  Match one or two digits
)?         End capture group, question mark indicates optional
$          End of string/line (depending on flags)
```